# How are some sites able to bypass vpn?

Tags: vpn

I have seen many sites which I couldn't open even if i try to access using VPN. Eg: deezer. Any method how to access the website in such cases? Well I use free vpn mainly open vpn.

Comment: Explain what type of VPN you use, paid, free or via your company.

Answer (score 3):

They dont bypass VPN. They in most cases have a blanket block on all "Anonymous VPNs".
Such lists are available by many IP blacklists vendors and there is also DNSBL's containing IPs of Anonymous VPN providers and Proxy servers.